# What does this piece of c code do?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I came across this piece of code, but am not able to entirely make sense of it:

```
(((x)[y] << 8) | (x)[(y)+1])
```

where x is a pointer to a const unsigned char and y is an integer.

Comment: Looks like it came from a macro, or maybe a Lisp programmer. It's combining two 8 bit values into a single 16 bit value. The first byte becomes the MSB and the second byte becomes the LSB.

Comment: What part is not obvious? The vertical bars? The semicircles around `x` and `y`?

Comment: Be more clear about what you don't understand.  "What does this code do?" is not a clear question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It extracts the 16-bit big-endian value starting at index `y` from array `x`.